# Allow two feature modules to work on the same NGRX/store without overwriting

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I've just started to set up an NGRX/Store based sample project.
My goal was to develop independent feature modules working on the same store. Later, these modules are to be outsourced to a library so that they can be integrated independently.

---

**I have provided this really simple test project as a Stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/github/MarcManhart/ngrx-beispiel-projekt

---

Both modules load the data in their main components via an action, which in turn triggers an effect and which in turn obtains the data from a service. The classic way as far as I understand it.

However, it happens that these data overwrite each other if I first use the admin module to add data records and then navigate to the customer module.

So I have the feeling that I didn't integrate the store correctly. Can anybody help me further?

The components (each in its own module):

```typescript
export class AdminHomeComponent implements OnInit {

  movies$: Observable<Movie[]> = this.store.pipe(select(selectAllMovies));

  constructor(private store: Store<fromReducer.State>) {
    this.store.dispatch(loadMovies());
  }

  //...
}
```

```typescript
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {

  movies$: Observable<Movie[]> = this.store.pipe(select(selectAllMovies));

  constructor(private store: Store<fromReducer.State>) {
    this.store.dispatch(loadMovies());
  }

  //...
}
```

The action:

```typescript
export const loadMovies = createAction('[Movies] Load movie');
```

The Effect:

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class MovieEffects {

  loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(MovieActions.loadMovies),
      mergeMap(() => this.movieService.getAll() // service returns data from API
      .pipe(
        map(movies => {
          return MovieActions.loadMoviesSuccess({movies: movies});
        }),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      ))
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private movieService: MovieService
  ) {
  }
}
```

Comment: They are overwriting data since these module are using the same featureKey, 'movies-state'. You can see your application state and running actions if you install redux devtool

Comment: Also, even though he has 2 feature modules, they are using the same action... the store in both modules looks the same, if so, they probably don't need to be separate modules... looks DRY to me

Comment: Yes that's true, but my goal is to use the same data store. How else should I implement this?

Comment: Since one module is for management and one module is for the "consumer" user ( is that right? ), maybe it is a better idea to use two distinct featureKey, ed. 'movies-management' and 'movies-customer'. These modules then can work individually or together, working on their state namespace ( the application state will be one in all cases ).

Comment: As @SergioRinaudo says, don't worry about the global State, it will be declared once by the final App, and your feature Stores will simply add their properties to it. And I agree also, check the Redux DevTools, you will see how your Store gets scaffolded !

Comment: Okay, maybe the problem here is that I don't understand how it can then be the same data. If my app-state consists of two feature-keys (since each module uses its own), redundant data storage is created, isn't it? (Appstate)-->(Management)-->(movies) then has e.g. three entries while (Appstate)-->(Customer)-->(movies) has e.g. only one or is outdated, or something like that.

Comment: I forket the stackblitz with different feature-keys. It still seems to override the other when second module is loaded later. https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-pbrsbd

Comment: @EchtFettigerKeks, let me ensure I understand your problem correctly - you want to have two separate lazy-loaded feature modules, but also want them to have the access to one shared data store, where both feature modules would use all the same actions and selectors?